# Complex inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Image of Problem 7.95]

Problem from Schaum’s Outlines of Linear Algebra 6th Ed (2017, McGraw-Hill)

I proved that ***a*** and ***d*** must be real positive, and ***b*** is the conjugate of ***c***.
The solution indicates that ***a.d-b.c*** must also be positive, but i can't figure that out.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Possibly impose the condition that $<v,v>  \geq  0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1:  $f(u,v) = u \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \overline{v}^T$.

Hint 2:

> What happens to $f(u,u)$ if the determinant of that matrix is negative?

Comment: Thank you, but i still can't see how the determinant of that Hermitian matrix is relevant ?

Comment: @Hsazerty : What is the sign constraint on $\langle u,u \rangle$?

Comment: ⟨u,u⟩ is always greater than or equals zero.

Comment: @Hsazerty : Now wave your mouse over the gray box in the Answer and answer the question there.

Comment: you mean if the determinant is negative, then f(u,u) may be negative for some u, and hence it is not a scalar product ?
Well, it's not really obvious to me...i proved that for a real matrix (positive definite)...but for the complexe case...i don't know.

Comment: @Hsazerty : If the determinant is negative, since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, at least one eigenvalue is negative.  What happens to $f(u,u)$ when $u$ is *any* vector in the eigenspace corresponding to that negative eigenvalue?

Comment: Please note that the problem was introduced in chapter 7 - Inner Product Spaces, Orthogonality.

Comment: @Hsazerty : The matrix form of an inner product must be [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix), a term which is defined for real symmetric matrices and for complex Hermitian matrices.  You have already shown the complex matrix is Hermitian.  (Simultaneously, you have shown that $f$ is a real-valued function.)  Now **finish**.

Comment: Sorry...but i still can't see the finish...maybe i missed something...

Comment: @Hsazerty : You are required to enforce positive definiteness.  You have not enforced positive definiteness.  You are not finished.

Comment: if f(u,v) is a scalar product, then f(u,u) must be positive for all u in C2, which means that the above matrix must be positive definite, and for that its determinant should be positive. and we already proved that the above matrix is hermitian. So all the conditions are :
a and d real positive, b is the conjugate of c, and the determinant is positive.
Conversely, if all the above conditions are satisfied, then the matrix is hermitian and definite positive, so f(u,v) is a scalar product. Right ?

Comment: Yes.  So what does "$a \cdot d - b \cdot c$" have to do with the determinant?

Comment: A 2x2 matrix is positive definite iff the diagonal entries a and d are real positive and the determinant a.d-b.c is positive. Right ?

Comment: a.d-b.c is the determinant of the above matrix.

Comment: And also b is the conjugate of c

Comment: @Hsazerty : "$b$ is the conjugate of $c$" is part of "the matrix is Hermitian", a requirement for the definition of positive definite.  So stating that means you are backtracking.

Comment: Well well, i don't see what is wrong.

Comment: @Hsazerty : Quoting from the Question, "The solution indicates that a.d-b.c must also be positive, but i can't figure that out."  Since you now cannot see what is wrong, this Answer has completely resolved your Question.  You should mark it as having done so.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated.